# Mathematical philosophy

Tags: book-recommendation, philosophy

I have seen that they have already asked before in this forum for recommendations for books about mathematical philosophy, but I think my case is particular. I have never read anything about it and I would like to start with an easy-to-read book, since at the moment I am devoting my energy to studying other topics, but I would like to gradually delve into this topic that has caught my attention. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider [The Mathematical Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Experience)

Comment: Thanks, I read a little about it and it seems like an excellent book. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you would like to read [The Mathematical Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Experience) by Davis and Hersh.

Comment: It is an easy-to-read book to delve gradually into mathematical philosophy